# Grab SSH Key contents and make an Authorized Keys file

Tags: ssh, key, ssh-keys

all I have a script that generates ssh keys and the renames the pub key to the users name.key I now want to take all the users keys contents and make an authorized keys file out of it. I know I can use the find command not sure how to fully implement it.

Comment: Where are the files located? If all in the same dir, just issue `cat *.key > authorized_keys`

Comment: Damien, So all the keys are located in a sub directory of a user so it would be /username/username.key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
find . -name "*key" -exec cat {} >> ./authorized_keys \;
```

This will put the content of all files ending with `key`, found in the current directory and its children, into a file name `authorized_keys` in the current directory.